# pl-sql errror on select HR schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i want to do something like that.. but in a function.. select * from employees where employee_id = &employee_id   in HR schema of oracle

Q: Create Function “SEARCH_EMPLOYEE” that receives an Employee ID and returns all its attributes through an output parameter with a data structure that represents all its information

R:

```
Create or replace FUNCTION get_complete_employee (&in_employee_id IN NUMBER) 
    AS person_details;
    BEGIN 
    SELECT * --'Name-'||first_name||' '|| last_name
    into person_details
    FROM employees;   
   Dbms_output.put_line(person_details);
    -- END get_complete_employee;
    end;
```

i have a error of sintax  i guess..
 i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Please use English and no other languages in your question

Comment: What is the `person_details`? is it some kind of UDT?

Comment: person_details is just a word...
i want select * from employees and return that row where employee_id = &employee_id, however, the procedure dont return nathing

Comment: i want to do something like that.. but in a function..

select * from employees
where employee_id = &employee_id

Comment: Why don't you show the actual errors?  Why do you expect people to guess what they are?

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning how to create the function which returns entire row of the table then following is the basic example of doing the same:

**Table data:**

```
SQL> select * from EMP;

    EMP_ID EMP_NAME             E
---------- -------------------- -
        10 John                 N
        20 May                  Y

SQL>
```

**Function:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_COMPLETE_EMPLOYEE (
  2      IN_EMPLOYEE_ID IN   NUMBER
  3  ) RETURN EMP%ROWTYPE AS
  4      MY_ROWTYPE   EMP%ROWTYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6      SELECT
  7          * --'Name-'||first_name||' '|| last_name
  8      INTO MY_ROWTYPE
  9      FROM
 10          EMP
 11      WHERE
 12          EMP_ID = IN_EMPLOYEE_ID;
 13
 14      RETURN MY_ROWTYPE;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

**Calling the function and result:**

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2      EMPTYPE   EMP%ROWTYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4      EMPTYPE := GET_COMPLETE_EMPLOYEE(10);
  5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EMPTYPE.EMP_NAME);
  6  END;
  7  /
John
```

You must have to handle multiple exception scenarios in real-world coding.

Cheers!!